# How to pass a Tuple Parameter to the ibm_db python module?

Tags: python, db2

Env:  Python 3.7 64bit with ibm_db module.

following lines fail with "Param is not a tuple" no matter what i try.  Although this was easy using the DB2 ODBC driver an pyodbc.

```
oStatement = ibm_db.prepare(oCon, sSQL)  # SQL Statement has one "?"  
x = ibm_db.execute(oStatement, (10))  
#I've tried so many variations of the line above like:  10 by itself or ((10)) in case it needs to be prepared for a list, I've tried [10]....
```

It is worth noting that performing a manual ibm_db.bind_param on one parameter at a time does work fine but documentation says i should be able to dynamically bind from a tuple.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `10`, `(10)` or `((10))` are tuples. `(10,)` is a tuple.

Comment: forgot to mention i also already tried (10,)  same results.... 'Param not a tuple'

Comment: actually my apologies... i just went back to try that again... and it works... i must have had something else wrong when i tried that earlier....   Btw pyodbc allows (10) without a following comma when passing single/array params to db calls.... only when i switched to pure ibm_db did it bark.  Thanks!!!